# Is it possible to parse by hxt <textarea> with <a> in it?

Tags: html, haskell, hxt

I use hxt to parse some html. It hase unescaped html inside `<textarea>`. hxt gives invalid results (it stumbles upon a tag with content in this case it's `<a>`). Minimal testcase (for GHCi) is

```
let doc = parseHtml "<textarea>before<a>link</a>after</textarea>"
runX . xshow $ doc //> hasName "textarea"
```

which gives `[<textarea>before</textarea><textarea/>]` as a result.

It looks like tags with no contents (e.g. `<tag/>`) do not break parsing.

Is there any way to parse such html with hxt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that [HandsomeSoup](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HandsomeSoup) (which I'm assuming is where your `parseHTML` is from) is picky about things like the fact that a `textarea` can't contain an `a` in valid HTML, and will try to "fix" any such errors it sees.

Can you switch to [hxt-tagsoup](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hxt-tagsoup)? It will still accept messy HTML (unclosed elements, etc.), but isn't so fussy about adherence to the HTML schema—specifically it will let you have an `a` in a `textarea`:

```
import Text.XML.HXT.Core
import Text.XML.HXT.TagSoup

let content = "<textarea>before<a>link</a>after</textarea>"
let doc = readString [ withTagSoup ] content
runX . xshow $ doc //> hasName "textarea"
```

This prints the following:

```
["<textarea>before<a>link</a>after</textarea>"]
```

Which I think is what you want.

Comment: The other option I took a look at is html-conduit with [dom-selector](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/dom-selector) it uses Text so it should be more effective but for my task efficiency is not a big problem and hxt arrow interface looks somewhat more intuitive, so I go with your solution, thanks